# Get install path of modified installation

Tags: c#, winforms

We allow our users to modify our installation package (by using MageUI). MageUI however deletes the entry that will install an icon on the desktop. During this process the users may change the name of the product and the publisher in the different manifests. This results that the instruction to create a desktop shortcut is missing and that the  "Installation" publisher will then be different than the original application vendor. I need to get the location where the application was installed in order to create a desktop shortcut during the applications first run. Function such as Application.StartupPath can not do as these paths will change when the application is upgraded (via Click Once).

On Windows 8.1 the application is available on the Start Menu (the one with all the apps) If I right click on the program there I can get to the file location. I assume it is that location that I need for the creation of the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a `Application.StartupPath` which points to your application. (Works only with WinForms.

In case you have something else, try reflection:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```